# Remove/Hide the URL shown on Azure AD B2C on Android

Tags: android, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have integrated Azure AD B2C using MSAL library on Native Android, created the user flow for `SignInSignUp` .once the Webview for `SignIn/SignUp` launches on my app, `URL` is also shown on the launching page. Is there any way to hide that `URL` or any other way we can restrict the user from seeing it?  you can also see the image on the attached link below for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBXvX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use the web view UX to hide the url

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authorization-agents

Answer (score 0):

I have added the below code to my `auth_config_b2c.json` , and now the URL is not showing :

Code :

"authorization_user_agent" : "WEBVIEW"